# C# всё-таки в какой момент создается экземпляр объекта в памяти? В момент вызова конструктора или в момент написания имени после типа?

Tags: c#, объекты, память

Судя по всему в момент задания имени после написания типа (StructSquare sq2),
но такой объект ещё не инициализирован, а инициализировать его можно по-разному. Как объяснить возможность вызова нестатичных методов из не проинициализированных сущностей

```
internal struct StructSquare
{
    public int AreaSquare()
    {
        return 967;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StructSquare sq2;
        Console.WriteLine(sq2.AreaSquare());
    }
}
```

Comment: У структуры всегда есть конструктор по умолчанию. С чего вы решили, что объект не инициализирован?

Comment: Это я понимаю, но я ведь его не вызвал, нет new(). Или он в данном случает и без new() автоматически вызывается?

Comment: У структур он сам вызывается. У классов надо вызывать.

Comment: Интересная тонкость, даже new() необязательно писать. Ладно, спасибо за ответ. Только что проверил с классами(как я мог забыть заранее это проверить) и действительно, с классами такая штука уже не проходит

Comment: Если вопрос именно про память - то для структуры память выделяется в стеке в момент захода в метод (даже если она объявлена ниже), для класса - в момент вызова new()